# Selenium, BeatifulSoup, Requests in a loop

Tags: python, selenium, python-requests

I am just being curious because I am trying to learn python. I am extracting data from a website. Anyway, what I did is scroll the page, then get the title that corresponds with the URL and inside a loop I am requesting this URL and extracting it with BS. Obviously, it doesn't work, the HTML that I am requesting prints like this:

```
<html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the python code

```
import time
import requests

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

chromedriver = "/Users/eduardfossas/Downloads/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)

my_url = driver.get("https://wodwell.com/wods/?sort=newest&category=none&feeds=736")
time.sleep(1)

elem = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body")

no_of_pagedowns = 20

while no_of_pagedowns:
    elem.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
    time.sleep(0)
    no_of_pagedowns-=1

containers = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('wod-title')

for container in containers:

    my_sub_url = "https://wodwell.com/wod/"
    my_sub_url = my_sub_url + container.text + '/'
    page_html = requests.get(my_sub_url).text

    page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

    main_text = page_soup.select('.workout-list')
```

Is there any way to make this work with BeatifulSoup and requests? If not, I think I am going to try Scrapy.

What do you recommend?

Kind regards and many thanks.

Comment: Looks like your request is failing with a 403 error. It worked OK on my system.

Comment: @ggorlen what OS are u using? I am on a macOS with high sierra. Did you try to print the var main_text? Thanks!

Comment: It has nothing to do with OS because it's about request protocol. Sometimes it depends on your geography too. Where are you from @user1888427?

Comment: @ggorlen, it worked! I had to specify the headers for chrome 

headers = {'user-agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36'}
    page_html = requests.get(my_sub_url, headers = headers).text

Answer (score 0):

That never happened to me.

Maybe it will be useful for someone, it worked as soon as specified the headers:

```
headers = {'user-agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36'}
page_html = requests.get(my_sub_url, headers = headers).text
```